# Test cached (multiprocessed) and memoized method

Tags: ruby, multithreading, testing, rspec

Short question, I'd like to test this method `foo`:

```
class MyClass
    def foo
        # The `@cache_key` is defined by instance but can be the same for
        # different instances (obviously I guess)
        @foo ||= cache.fetch(@cache_key) do
            # call a private method, tested aside
            generate_foo_value || return
            # The `|| return` trick is one I use to skip the yield result
            # in case of falsey value. May not be related to the question,
            # but I left it there because I'm not so sure.
        end
   end
end
```

The issue here is that I have two kinds of caching.

On one hand, I have `@foo ||=` that assure memoization and that I can test pretty easily. For instance by calling twice my method and watch if the result is different.

On the other hand, I have the `cache.fetch` method which may be shared between different instances. The trouble for me is here: I don't know the best way to **unit** test it. Should I mock my cache? Should I watch cache result? Or should I run plural instances with the same cache key?

And for this last question, I don't know how to run plural instances easily using `rspec`.

Comment: are you running your tests in parallel? If not, then you could possily clear the cache each test. In either case I'm not really surewhatyou mean "plural instances", can you show an example of such a test?

Comment: No, they're not run in parallel. And I cannot since it's specifically this I don't know how to do. But what I would like to achieve is checking if when I run two instances (something like using two `subjects`), I have two times the same result. Mocking the cache key attribute to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need plural instances in this case. It looks like you could just set the cache value in the specs and test that the MyClass instance(s) is returning it.

```
before { cache.set(:cache_key, 'this is from cache') }
subject { MyClass.new(:cache_key, cache) } # you didn't provide the
                                           # initializer, so I'll just assume
                                           # that you can set the cache key 
                                           # and inject the cache object 

specify do 
  expect(subject.foo).to eq 'this is from cache'
end
```

You can also set the expectation that `generate_foo_value` is not run at all in this case.

My reasoning is that: you don't need to fully emulate setting the cache in a separate process. You test only that if the cache with the key is set - your method has to return it instead of doing expensive computation.

The fact that this cache is `shared` between processes (like it sits in a PostgreSQL DB, or Redis or whatever) is irrelevant for the test.

Comment: I've done this test of expecting `generate_foo_value` not to be called, it looks like a good idea indeed. My question left is, is it a good idea not to mock the cache. I'm not accepting for now, in order to see if there is any solution that seems more _good practice_. Yours seems already pretty nice. (my `cache_key` is, in fact, a method, but I thought it was not very relevant to point that out for this mcve)

Comment: Sure, in case `cache` object is communicating with some real cache backend (Redis? PG?), probably the best is to mock it. Or you can just make ad-hoc object with the same interface as `cache` and implement in-class cache there (in case you don't like mocks). Of course - the `cache` object should be covered separately as well.